# Forecast Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, regression, forecasting

Apologies if this is a bit of a simple question, but I haven't been able to find any answer to this over the past week and it's driving me crazy.

**Background Info:** I have a dataset that tracks the weight of 5 individuals over 5 years. Each year, I have a distribution for the weight of individuals in the group, from which I calculate the mean and standard deviation. Data is as follows:

```
 Year = [2002,2003,2004,2005,2006]
 Weights_2002 = [12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
 Weights_2003 = [14, 16, 18, 20,20]
 Weights_2004 = [16, 18, 20, 22, 18]
 Weights_2005 = [18, 21, 22, 22, 20]
 Weights_2006 = [2, 21, 19, 20, 20]
```

**The Question:** How do I project annual distributions of weight for the group the next 10 years? Ideally, I would like the uncertainty about the mean to increase as time goes on. Likewise, I would like the uncertainty about the standard deviation to increase too. Phrased another way, I would like to project the distributions of weight going forward, accounting for both:

1. Natural Variance in the Data
2. Increasing uncertainty.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. If anyone can suggest how to do this in R, that would be even better.

Thanks guys!

Comment: These two resources http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html & http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast/ provide great tutorials on doing forecasting with R.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I've had a look though both previously, but can't seem to find something that makes projections that account for the natural variance in the data and increasing uncertainty. Perhaps I'm missing something... I've also carried out a projection using the Holt-Winters package in R but I believe that can only input the mean of the data. It doesn't seem to account for the natural variance. But thank you for the quick response and suggestions

Comment: Do you want the projections based on the whole group or for each individual?

Comment: I want projections for the whole group. I want to project how the group's distributions of weights will change over time. Just like I have a distribution of weight for the group in 2006, I would like to forecast a distribution of weight for the group in 2007 too. Hope that's clear

Comment: It seems like an application of a hierarchical analysis, where you model the group trend and the variance. But I am not sure how you can model "uncertainty" in the future as a function of time. This information is not contained in the existing data and therefore has to be supplied externally, I imagine.

Comment: Is the value `2` in `Weights_2006` an outlier or a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absent specific suggestions on how to use the forecasting tools in R, *viz.* the comments to your question, here is an alternative approach that uses Monte Carlo simulation.

First, some housekeeping: the value `2` in `Weights_2006` is either a typo or an outlier. Since I can't tell which, I will assume it's an outlier and exclude it from the analysis.

Second, you say you want to project the distributions based on `increasing uncertainty`. But your data doesn't support that.

```
Year <- c(2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)
W2   <- c(12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
W3   <- c(14, 16, 18, 20,20)
W4   <- c(16, 18, 20, 22, 18)
W5   <- c(18, 21, 22, 22, 20)
W6   <- c(NA, 21, 19, 20, 20)
df   <- rbind(W2,W3,W4,W5,W6)
df   <- data.frame(Year,df)

library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(ggplot2)
data <- melt(df,id="Year", variable.name="Individual",value.name="Weight")
ggplot(data)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Weight),binwidth=1,fill="lightgreen",colour="grey50")+
  facet_grid(Year~.)
```

[image]

The mean weight goes up over time, but the variance *decreases*. A look at the individual time series shows why.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Weight, color=Individual))+geom_line()
```

[image]

In general, an individual's weight increases linearly with time (about 2 units per year), until it reaches 20, when it stops increasing but fluctuates. Since your initial distribution was uniform, the individuals with lower weight saw an increase over time, driving the mean up. But the weight of heavier individuals stopped growing. So the distribution gets "bunched up" around 20, resulting in a decreasing variance. We can see this in the numbers: increasing mean, decreasing standard deviation.

```
smry <- function(x)c(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x))
aggregate(Weight~Year,data,smry)
#   Year Weight.mean  Weight.sd
# 1 2002  16.0000000  3.1622777
# 2 2003  17.6000000  2.6076810
# 3 2004  18.8000000  2.2803509
# 4 2005  20.6000000  1.6733201
# 5 2006  20.0000000  0.8164966
```

We can model this behavior using a Monte Carlo simulation.

```
set.seed(1)
start <- runif(1000,12,20)
X <- start
result <- X
for (i in 2003:2008){
  X <- X + 2
  X <- ifelse(X<20,X,20) +rnorm(length(X))
  result <- rbind(result,X)
}
result <- data.frame(Year=2002:2008,result)
```

In this model, we start with 1000 individuals whose weight forms a uniform distribution between 12 and 20, as in your data. At each time step we increase the weights by 2 units. If the result is >20 we clip it to 20. Then we add random noise distributed as N[0,1]. Now we can plot the distributions.

```
model <- melt(result,id="Year",variable.name="Individual",value.name="Weight")
ggplot(model,aes(x=Weight))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),fill="lightgreen",colour="grey50",bins=20)+
  stat_density(geom="line",colour="blue")+
  geom_vline(data=aggregate(Weight~Year,model,mean), aes(xintercept=Weight), colour="red", size=2, linetype=2)+
  facet_grid(Year~.,scales="free")
```

[image]

The red bars show the mean weight in each year.

If you believe that the natural variation in the weight of an individual increases over time, then use `N[0,sigma]` as the error term in the model, with `sigma` increasing with `Year`. The problem is that there is nothing in your data to support that.